# selecting second child in beautiful soup with soup.select?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have:

```
<h2 id='names'>Names</h2>
<p>John</p>
<p>Peter</p>
```

now what's the easiest way to get the Peter here if I have h2 tag already? Now I've tried:

```
soup.select("#names > p:nth-child(1)")
```

but here I get nth-child NotImplementedError:

```
NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.
```

So I'm not sure what's going on here. The second option was to just get all 'p' tag  children and hard select [1] but then there's a danger of index out of range which would require to surround every attempt to get *Peter* with try/except which is a bit silly.

Any way to select nth-child with soup.select() function?

**EDIT:**
replacing nth-child with nth-of-type seemed to do the trick, so the correct line is:

```
soup.select("#names > p:nth-of-type(1)")
```

not sure why it doesn't accept nth-child but it seems that both nth-child and nth-of-type return the same results.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Adding your edit as an answer so that it can be more easily found by others:

Use `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`:

```
soup.select("#names > p:nth-of-type(1)")
```

Answer (score 8):

'nth-of-child' is simply not implemented in beautifulsoup4 (at time of writing), there is simply no code in the beautifulsoup codebase to do it. The authors explicitly added the 'NotImplementedError' to explain this, [here is the code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py?start_revid=342#L1261)

Given the html you quote in your question you are not looking for a child of h2#names.

What you are really looking for is the second adjacent sibling, I'm not a css selector guru but I found that this worked.

```
soup.select("#names + p + p")
```

Comment: it did works indeed, however I did it with nth-of-type instead of nth-child which seemed to do the trick as well.

Answer (score 3):

Beautiful Soup 4.7.0 (released at the beginning of 2019) [now supports](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) most selectors, including `:nth-child`:

> As of version 4.7.0, Beautiful Soup supports most CSS4 selectors via the SoupSieve project. If you installed Beautiful Soup through `pip`, SoupSieve was installed at the same time, so you don’t have to do anything extra.

So, if you upgrade your version:

```
pip install bs4 -U
```

You'll be able to use nearly all selectors you'd ever need to, including `nth-child`.

That said, note that in your input HTML, the `#names` `h2` tag does not actually have any children:

```
<h2 id='names'>Names</h2>
<p>John</p>
<p>Peter</p>
```

Here, there are just 3 elements, which are all siblings, so

```
#names > p:nth-child(1)
```

wouldn't work, even in CSS or Javascript.

If the `#names` element had the `<p>`s as *children*, your selector would work, to an extent:

```
html = '''
<div id='names'>
    <p>John</p>
    <p>Peter</p>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.select("#names > p:nth-child(1)")
```

Output:

```
[<p>John</p>]
```

Of course, the `John` `<p>` is the first child of the `#names` parent. If you want `Peter`, use `:nth-child(2)`.

If the elements are all adjacent siblings, you can use `+` to select the next sibling:

```
html = '''
<h2 id='names'>Names</h2>
<p>John</p>
<p>Peter</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
soup.select("#names + p + p")
```

Output:

```
[<p>Peter</p>]
```

Comment: The correct syntax is "nth-of-type" / "nth-of-child"  your syntax is not working no matter the version

Comment: I know I tested all the snippets before posting the answer. I just tried it again, and the snippets all worked on my end. There is no such thing as [`nth-of-child`](https://www.google.com/search?q=nth+of+child). `nth-child` is a proper selector and works (see [CSS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)), as is [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

Comment: If it doesn't exist, why is it right in the first example of the very first link you posted? You're contradicting yourself

Comment: I don't see it listed anywhere... https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQJeH.png `nth-of-child` does not exist. (In contrast, both `nth-child` and `nth-of-type`, which are standard CSS selectors, do exist)