# BeautifulSoup use unique CSS Selector

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

From this [page](https://www.placetel.de/status), I need to get the status from "Anbindung an das Telefonnetz".

I identified 2 ways to get it:

1. If the status contains the sentence "Das System arbeitet einwandfrei";
2. If the color of the background is green.

I have chosen to go with the first option.

I use Python/BeautifulSoup to scrape the page. The thing is, there is no unique id/class or whatsoever to get this element. 
I then decided to use the CSS selector of this particular element, which is the following:

```
div.system-item:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(3)
```

And use it like this:

```
print(page.select("div.system-item:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(3)"))
```

However, the only thing I get is an empty element (`[]`).

What could I try more to get this particular element?

**EDIT** 
As some of you recommend it, here is the un-complete HTML source of the page.
. But to be practical, i recommend you to just take a look yourself at the [page](https://www.placetel.de/status)

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

            <title>Aktueller Status | Placetel</title>

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="756F6E40DD887A659CE83E5A92FFBB62">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <meta name="generator" content="Kirby 2.3.2">

    <meta name="description" content="Placetel Systemstatus: Erfahren Sie mehr &uuml;ber den aktuellen Status der Placetel Telefonanlage.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow,noodp,noydir">

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.placetel.de/status">
    <link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/b/111027512373770716962/111027512373770716962/posts">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#0e70b9">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-tile-icon.png">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#0e70b9">

    <script src="//use.typekit.net/rnw8lad.js"></script>
    <script>try { Typekit.load({ async: true }); } catch (e) {}</script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/css/main.css">    <script src="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//app.marketizator.com"/>
    <script>
        var _mktz = _mktz || [];
        _mktz.cc_domain = 'placetel.de';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//d2tgfbvjf3q6hn.cloudfront.net/js/o17fe41.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="" class="page page-template-page-sections page-uid-status">

<script>
    var gaProperty = 'UA-17631409-3';
    var disableStr = 'ga-disable-' + gaProperty;
    if (document.cookie.indexOf(disableStr + '=true') > -1) {
        window[disableStr] = true;
    }
    function gaOptout() {
        document.cookie = disableStr + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
        window[disableStr] = true;
    }
</script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KDNGCC"
                  height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
        new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                                                  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
        '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KDNGCC');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
<header class="header header-condensed" id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">

<nav class="navigation navigation-top">
    <ul>
                    <li class=" ">
                <a title="Unternehmen" href="https://www.placetel.de/unternehmen">

                    <span>Unternehmen</span>
                </a>
            </li>
                    <li class=" ">
                <a title="Partner werden" href="https://www.placetel.de/partner">

                    <span>Partner werden</span>
                </a>
            </li>
                    <li class=" ">
                <a title="Support" href="https://www.placetel.de/support">

                    <span>Support</span>
                </a>
            </li>
                    <li class=" ">
                <a title="Suche" href="javascript:modal('search')">

                    <span>Suche</span>
                </a>
            </li>
                <li class="navigation-top-support">
            <a href="https://www.placetel.de/support">
                <svg class="svg-phone"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-phone"></use></svg>                <span>0221 29 191 999</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-top-login">
            <a href="https://app.placetel.de/account/login">
                <span>Login</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="site-logo" href="https://www.placetel.de">
            <svg class="svg-placetel-logo"><title>Placetel</title> <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-placetel-logo"></use></svg>        </a>

<nav class="navigation navigation-main" id="navigation-main">
    <ul>

            <li class="has-sub-navigation">
                <a title="Telefonanlage" href="https://www.placetel.de/telefonanlage"
                   class="">
                    <span>Telefonanlage</span>

                                            <svg class="svg-arrow"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-arrow"></use></svg>                                    </a>

                                    <nav class="sub-navigation">
                        <ul>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/telefonanlage">
                                        Vorteile                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/telefonanlage/preise">
                                        Preise                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/telefonanlage/funktionen">
                                        Funktionen                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/telefonanlage/unified-communication">
                                        Unified Communication                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/telefonanlage/funktionsweise">
                                        Wie funktioniert es?                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/telefonanlage/isdn-abschaltung">
                                        ISDN-Abschaltung                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/telefonanlage/faq">
                                        FAQ                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                    </ul>
                    </nav>
                            </li>

            <li class="">
                <a title="Trunking" href="https://www.placetel.de/sip-trunking"
                   class="">
                    <span>Trunking</span>

                                    </a>

                            </li>

            <li class="">
                <a title="Mobilfunk" href="https://www.placetel.de/mobilfunk"
                   class="">
                    <span>Mobilfunk</span>

                                    </a>

                            </li>

            <li class="navigation-main-shop">
                <a title="Endger&auml;te-Shop" href="/shop/"
                   class="">
                    <span>Endger&auml;te-Shop</span>

                                    </a>

                            </li>

            <li class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block">
                <a title="Support" href="https://www.placetel.de/support"
                   class="">
                    <span>Support</span>

                                    </a>

                            </li>

            <li class="visible-xs-block visible-sm-block">
                <a title="Partner" href="https://www.placetel.de/partner"
                   class="">
                    <span>Partner</span>

                                    </a>

                            </li>

            <li class="has-sub-navigation visible-xs-block visible-sm-block">
                <a title="Unternehmen" href="https://www.placetel.de/unternehmen"
                   class="">
                    <span>Unternehmen</span>

                                            <svg class="svg-arrow"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-arrow"></use></svg>                                    </a>

                                    <nav class="sub-navigation">
                        <ul>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/unternehmen">
                                        &Uuml;ber uns                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/unternehmen/technologie">
                                        Technologie                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/unternehmen/jobs">
                                        Jobs                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/unternehmen/events">
                                        Events                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/unternehmen/presse">
                                        Presse                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                            <li class="">
                                    <a href="https://www.placetel.de/unternehmen/kontakt">
                                        Kontakt                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                                    </ul>
                    </nav>
                            </li>

            <li class="navigation-main-register">
                <a title="Kostenlos testen!" href="javascript:modal('register')"
                   class="btn">
                    <span>Kostenlos testen!</span>

                                    </a>

                            </li>
            </ul>
</nav>        
        <a class="site-navigation-toggle" id="hotdog">
            <i>
                <span></span>
            </i> Menü
        </a>
    </div>
</header>


            <section class="section section-full section-full-section-einleitung-text section-full-normal">
    <div class="container-fluid typography typography-dark">
                    <h2 class="section-full-title">Der Placetel System Status</h2>

                    <h3 class="section-full-subtitle">Jeden Tag einen Grund zur Freude.</h3>

                    <p>Wir bei Placetel haben ein Lieblingswort: „läuft“. Der Grund: Ihre Placetel Telefonanlage funktioniert nämlich immer. Darüber freuen wir uns natürlich riesig. Da aber erst eine geteilte Freude eine richtige Freude ist, haben wir Ihnen diese Statusseite eingerichtet.  Diese Seite informiert Sie jeden Tag über den einwandfreien Status Ihrer Anlage.<br />
Und falls etwas mal nicht so perfekt funktionieren sollte wie gewohnt, können Sie uns den Fehler gern  melden.</p>        
            </div>

            <style>
            .section-full-section-einleitung-text {
                background-color: ;
            }
        </style>

    </section>    

            <section class="section section-system">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-transparent btn-with-icon" href="javascript:location.reload();">
        <svg class="svg-refresh"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-refresh"></use></svg>        Status aktualisieren
    </a>

    <div class="system flex-grid typography typography-light">
        <div class="system-item system-item-green flex-grid-item">
            <div class="system-item-inner">
                <h6>
                    System                </h6>

                <i>
                    <svg class="svg-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-included"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-dots"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-dots"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-not-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-not-included"></use></svg>                </i>

                <p>
                    Das System arbeitet einwandfrei<br>
                    11:10 Uhr
                </p>

                            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="system-item system-item-green flex-grid-item">
            <div class="system-item-inner">
                <h6>
                    Anbindung an das  Telefonnetz                </h6>

                <i>
                    <svg class="svg-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-included"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-dots"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-dots"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-not-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-not-included"></use></svg>                </i>

                <p>
                    Das System arbeitet einwandfrei<br>
                    11:10 Uhr
                </p>

                            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="system-item system-item-green flex-grid-item">
            <div class="system-item-inner">
                <h6>
                    Faxsystem                </h6>

                <i>
                    <svg class="svg-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-included"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-dots"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-dots"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-not-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-not-included"></use></svg>                </i>

                <p>
                    Das System arbeitet einwandfrei<br>
                    11:10 Uhr
                </p>

                            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="system-item system-item-green flex-grid-item">
            <div class="system-item-inner">
                <h6>
                    Konferenzsystem                </h6>

                <i>
                    <svg class="svg-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-included"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-dots"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-dots"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-not-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-not-included"></use></svg>                </i>

                <p>
                    Das System arbeitet einwandfrei<br>
                    11:10 Uhr
                </p>

                            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="system-item system-item-green flex-grid-item">
            <div class="system-item-inner">
                <h6>
                    Features und Optionen                </h6>

                <i>
                    <svg class="svg-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-included"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-dots"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-dots"></use></svg>                    <svg class="svg-not-included"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="https://www.placetel.de/assets/dist/sprites/svg/sprite.1471515912.svg#svg-not-included"></use></svg>                </i>

                <p>
                    Das System arbeitet einwandfrei<br>
                    11:10 Uhr
                </p>

                            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you just get `div.system-item:nth-child(2)` and check whether or not this element has the class `system-item-green`?

Comment: Even if I only use `dix.system-item:nth-child(2)`, I got an empty element (`[]`)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `Das System arbeitet einwandfrei` appears multiple times, which one do you want?

Comment: The one in the 'case' Anbindung an das Telefonnetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know [nth-of-child](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24720912/4241180) is still not implemented in `BeautifulSoup4`. Also if you investigate the website's CSS (namely `_system.scss` file), you'll find out that there are 3 statuses:

1. `system-item-green`
2. `system-item-yellow`
3. `system-item-red`

So you may want to slightly change your code to be like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

url = 'https://www.placetel.de/status'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'
}
source = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BS(source.text, 'html.parser')

status = soup.select("div.system-item")[1].attrs['class']

if 'system-item-green' in status:
     print("It works!")
elif 'system-item-yellow' in status:
     print("Something's slightly wrong")
elif 'system-item-red' in status:
     print("Does not work")
else:
     print("Has someone changed page's markup?")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, how can you be sure that you select 'Anbindung and das Telefonnetz' since there is 4 different `div.sytem-item`?

Comment: @Mornor fire up python shell and go through the elements of list `soup.select("div.system-item")`. You will see that second element of the list (i.e. `soup.select("div.system-item")[1]`) is the one you needed.

Comment: Thank you for your solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the text to find the h6 for `Anbindung an das  Telefonnetz` and get the p sibling:

```
import requests
import re
r = requests.get("https://www.placetel.de/status").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

h6 = soup.find("h6", text=re.compile(ur"Anbindung an das  Telefonnetz", re.I))
if h6:
    print(h6.find_next_sibling("p"))
```

If you want full css3 selector support you can use *lxml's* [cssselect](http://lxml.de/cssselect.html):

```
from lxml import html
tree = html.fromstring(r)
print(tree.cssselect("div.system-item:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(3)")
```

You can also just search by the text so if the h6 turned to a h5 or any other tag it would make no odds:

```
match = soup.find(text=re.compile(ur"Anbindung an das  Telefonnetz", re.I))

if match:
    print(match.parent.find_next_sibling("p").text)
```

You could use the outer div to localise the search for the text, bs4 is pretty flexible. Just selecting all the `div.system-item` and indexing  would break if the order changed and you would not know as there would be no error so looking for the text is probably actually a safer approach.

Comment: Even a better solution. However, can you explain why you use `lxml` instead of  `html.parser`?

Comment: @Mornor, just habit more than anything, I wrote it without even thinking, also parsing with the lxml parser is faster and a lot of people have it installed when using bs4.  You can use html.parser and it will work fine.