# How to apply multiple arguments within find_all function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to use multiple arguments in a single `soup.find_all` function to find any particular item from certain elements? The process I wanna know about can easily be applied if i go for `soup.select` option. To be more specific: look at the below example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_element='''
<div class="browse-movie-bottom">
    <a href="https://yts.ag/movie/logan-lucky-2017" class="browse-movie-title">Logan Lucky</a>
    <div class="browse-movie-year">2017</div>
    <div class="browse-movie-tags">
        <a href="https://yts.ag/torrent/download" rel="nofollow" title="Logan Lucky">Logan Lucky 720p</a>
        <a href="https://yts.ag/torrent/download" rel="nofollow" title="Logan Lucky">Logan Lucky 1080p</a>
    </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_element,"lxml")
for item in soup.find_all(class_='browse-movie-bottom')[0].find_all(class_='browse-movie-tags')[0].find_all("a"):
# for item in soup.select(".browse-movie-bottom .browse-movie-tags a"):
    print(item.text)
```

On the one hand, I parsed movie tags using `soup.select()` which you know can be used in such a way so that all the arguments can fit together in a single brace.

On the other hand, I did the same using `soup.find_all()` which required three different arguments in three different braces. The results are same though.

My question is: whether it is possible to create any expression using `soup.find_all()` function which will include multiple arguments in a single brace as i did with `soup.select()`. Something like below:

This is a faulty one but it will give you an idea as to what type of expression i'm after:

```
soup.find_all({'class':'browse-movie-bottom'},{'class':'browse-movie-tags'},"a")[0]
```

However, the valid search results were:

```
Logan Lucky 720p
Logan Lucky 1080p
```

Comment: what are the drawbacks of `select` in this case ?

Comment: So, I should go for `find_all` function only if i encounter any drawback in `soup.select` function, is that what you meant @ PRMoureu? I would like to learn it. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass a list to `class_` atribute, this way you save one call to `find_all`, but you need to call it again with `"a"`, and allways you can just call like `soup("a")` using the shortcut to `find_all`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_element='''
<div class="browse-movie-bottom">
    <a href="https://yts.ag/movie/logan-lucky-2017" class="browse-movie-title">Logan Lucky</a>
    <div class="browse-movie-year">2017</div>
    <div class="browse-movie-tags">
        <a href="https://yts.ag/torrent/download" rel="nofollow" title="Logan Lucky">Logan Lucky 720p</a>
        <a href="https://yts.ag/torrent/download" rel="nofollow" title="Logan Lucky">Logan Lucky 1080p</a>
    </div>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_element,"lxml")
for item in soup.findAll(class_=['browse-movie-bottom', 'browse-movie-tags'])[1]('a'):
#for item in soup.select(".browse-movie-bottom .browse-movie-tags a"):
    print(item.text)
```

Comment: Thanks Rama, for your answer. It is very near to what i was expecting.

Comment: Just one thing: why does the index become `[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a CSS selector:

```
>>> soup.select(".browse-movie-bottom .browse-movie-tags a")
[<a href="https://yts.ag/torrent/download" rel="nofollow" title="Logan Lucky">Logan Lucky 720p</a>, <a href="https://yts.ag/torrent/download" rel="nofollow" title="Logan Lucky">Logan Lucky 1080p</a>]
>>> [item.text for item in soup.select(".browse-movie-bottom .browse-movie-tags a")]
[u'Logan Lucky 720p', u'Logan Lucky 1080p']
```

More info: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

Unless there's something you cannot do with CSS selectors (because not all of them are implemented), you should use `select`. Otherwise, use the more tedious `find_all`.

Example of non-implemented CSS-selector: n-th child.
[selecting second child in beautiful soup with soup.select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720442/selecting-second-child-in-beautiful-soup-with-soup-select)

Comment: @ Samuel GIFFARD ,what you have shown here i did it up there already. I wanted to know how to do the same with find_all function. You perhaps forgot to read the description. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Just edited it to give more information for you (or anyone who might wonder the same thing as you, in the future) :-)

Comment: @Topto If you feel that answer could help you or anyone in the future. Please validate and upvote it. If you don't please say in what way it is not satisfying, so that it can be improved.

Comment: Again I remind you about the title of this question. I only look for any answer related to find_all function not selector. Thanks.